# Differential equation of a LC circuit in series with a parallel RLC circuit

Tags: passive-networks, laplace-transform, step-response

I have the following RLC circuit. I am having trouble finding an expression for the natural response of this circuit.
I found a similar question, but I was unable to simplify exactly like was done in the question:
[How to construct a differential equation from this RLC circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365641/how-to-construct-a-differential-equation-from-this-rlc-circuit)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4UZ3n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is what I have done so far.

From KVL:
$$V_l + V_c + V_{out} - V_{in} = 0$$

From KCL:
$$I_1 + I_2 + I_3 - I_{in} = 0$$

Find currents:
$$I_3 = \frac{V_{out}}{R_1} ,  I_2 = C_2\frac{dV_{out}}{dt} ,  I_1 = \frac{1}{L_2}\int{V_{out}dt}$$

$$I_{in} = C_1\frac{dV_c}{dt} = \frac{1}{L_1}\int{V_ldt}$$

Differential equation:
$$\frac{1}{L_2}\int{V_{out}dt} + C_2\frac{dV_{out}}{dt} + \frac{V_{out}}{R_1} - C_1\frac{dV_c}{dt} = 0$$

The problem is I can't find a way to reduce the equation to one variable *Vout*. *Vc* cannot be simplified to only *Vout*. *Vl* needs to be known.

If Vc is found:
$$V_l = L_1\frac{dI_{in}}{dt}$$
$$V_c = V_{in} - V_{out} - L_1\frac{dI_{in}}{dt}$$

Then Substituted:
$$\frac{1}{L_2}\int{V_{out}dt} + C_2\frac{dV_{out}}{dt} + \frac{V_{out}}{R_1} - C_1\frac{d}{dt}(V_{in} - V_{out} - L_1\frac{dI_{in}}{dt}) = 0$$

But now *Vin* and *Iin* need to be known to simplify the equation. Their definition includes *Vc*, so it will just go round in circles.
Does anyone know how to simplify to only *Vout*?

Comment: I3=Vout / R1.  This needs to be fixed as a start.

Comment: You cannot specify both the input voltage source and the input current for it. Doesn't work. But assuming \$V_x\$ is the node between \$L_1\$ and \$C_1\$ and that I didn't make a mistake, KCL has:$$\begin{align*}
C_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} V_x+\frac1{L_1}\int V_x\:\text{d}t&=C_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} V_{_\text{OUT}}+\frac1{L_1}\int V_{_\text{IN}}\:\text{d}t
\\\\
C_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} V_{_\text{OUT}}+C_2\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} V_{_\text{OUT}}+\frac1{R_1}V_{_\text{OUT}}+\frac1{L_1}\int V_{_\text{OUT}}\:\text{d}t&=C_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} V_{x}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: sparpo, I'm hoping you realize this will not be a trivial excercise, since it is a 4th order bandpass (4 states: 2xL+2xC). A quick solve with wxMaxima shows it can't apply the inverse Laplace, and [Wolfram, well...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+laplace+%28C1*L2*R2*s%5E2%29%2F%28C1*C2*L1*L2*R2*s%5E4%2BC1*L1*L2*s%5E3%2B%28%28C2%2BC1%29*L2%2BC1*L1%29*R2*s%5E2%2BL2*s%2BR2%29). +1 for the effort, though.

Comment: @jonk Iin was just meant to represent the current in C1 or L1, not a specified current. I can see this might be unclear. With that equation, you still have 2 variables to solve, it still can't be simplified to only in terms of Vout?

Comment: @sparpo Does the work I show help, then?

Comment: @jonk No, unless there is a way to solve the equation with both Vx and Vout? Could partial differentiation be used?

Comment: I hope you’re not trying to solve the resulting equations… the final result of an exact solution will be a full-page affair. Setting up the equations and doing the transform is sure possible manually.

Comment: @sparpo The second equation can be very easily solved for \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} V_{x}\$. Substitute that result into the first equation, as appropriate, to get an equation relating \$ V_{_\text{OUT}}\$ and  \$ V_{_\text{IN}}\$. Solve for  \$ V_{_\text{OUT}}\$. Or shift into s-space and solve much more readily using algebra.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonk suggested, a shift in s-space give this ... Ok, don't try to see the "result" function.
It is more easily as there are no "initial" conditions ...

Also, a plot with some values ... (did not verify against "simulation" ... to be done).

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants it solved symbolically. That's why I said it's not trivial, because the roots of the denominator, only, take a fullscreen print with zoomed out text (and missing parts). :-)

Comment: EET should be used?